# Maps API get city and country

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, maps

I'm trying to compare what's in my autocomplete input field with formatted_address output.

I limit my autocomplete autocomplete with:

```
var options = {
      types: ['(cities)'],
     componentRestrictions: {country: "be"}
    };
```

and then take the output city with formatted_address.

Everything works fine, but for some cities I have a number that is added in the output and I can't compare it.

Example:
-This is comparable
Input field shows = Bruxelles, Belgique
Formatted_adress = Bruxelles, Belgique

-This isn't comparable
Input field shows = Malonne, Belgique
Formatted_adress = 5020 Malonne, Belgique

The question is: How to get exactly the same output as the showed input field?

```
///////EDIT
```

I thought I solved the problem by deleting these numbers:

```
//Delete numbers and spaces before output if they exist
while(from.charAt(0) == " " || (from.charAt(0) >= '0' && from.charAt(0) <= '9'))
   {
    from = from.substr(1);
    }
```

But you also have different languages:
Example:
Input field shows = Antwerpen, België
output = Anvers, Belgique

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I still not solved the problem. See new Edit

Answer (score 0):

The issue was to compare input field with hidden city input field.
Why?
1.Typing bruxelles
2. Select bruxelles
3. hidden city == bruxelles, hidden latlong = (xx,xx)

If submitting -> OK

If typing blabla and don't press enter, 
blabla will be input field with previous latlong hidden input.

So I wanted to compare hidden city with city input field.

The solution:
when typing -> clear hidden fields.

```
//Set from city hidden values to "" when typing again
     var input1 = document.getElementById('connexion_inputcity');

     input1.onkeydown = function() {
        var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

         if( key == 8 || key == 46 )
            {
            document.forms["inscription"]["check1"].value = "";
            document.forms["inscription"]["LatLongFrom"].value = "";
            }
         };

    input1.onkeypress = function () {
      document.forms["inscription"]["check1"].value = "";
      document.forms["inscription"]["LatLongFrom"].value = "";
    };


//Set to hidden hidden values to "" when typing again
     var input2 = document.getElementById('connexion_inputNdCity');

     input2.onkeydown = function() {
        var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

         if( key == 8 || key == 46 )
            {
            document.forms["inscription"]["check2"].value = "";
            document.forms["inscription"]["LatLongTo"].value = "";
            }
         };

    input2.onkeypress = function () {
      document.forms["inscription"]["check2"].value = "";
      document.forms["inscription"]["LatLongTo"].value = "";
    };
```